# .htaccess PHP Controller Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a PHP controller for testing purposes on my domain. The domain, by default, is entirely on Wordpress and I'm having issues setting up just the folder `testing1` to be controlled by my PHP controller. Here's the code in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule . /index.php

RewriteRule ^testing1/(.*)$ ./testing1/controller.php

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I go to `mydomain.com/testing1/` I get an internal server error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: your creating an infinite loop, change `./` to just `/` on your testing1 rewriterule

Comment: Still not working unfortunately...

Comment: Check the server's error log. it'll have more details about the 500 error than you'll ever see in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of `./`, which is used to point to current directory.

`RewriteRule ^testing1/(.*)$ testing1/controller.php`

I have it working.

Comment: That works great, one question though, now all the CSS and JS files in my controller are rewritten by that same rule. It appears that the RewriteCond's aren't working... How do I make sure that those files are untouched by the RewriteRule's?

Comment: The simplest way is to update the rewrite rule above to 'RewriteRule ^test/(.*).php$ test/controller.php'. So all css and js files will not be caught unless it is a php file.

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteRules are executed in order. If one does match, the rest is ignored. 
So the result might look like this (just the RewriteRules):

```
RewriteRule ^testing1/(.*)$ /testing1/controller.php    
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

The second rule does mean that when you type exactly one character (whatever it is), you will get directed to index.php. I don't know though if that is your intended behaviour.